# Why does serializing Integer take so many (81) bytes?

Tags: java, serialization

I wrote a small test program to show how many bytes we need to serialize `Integer` object:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(data);
        output.writeObject(1);
        output.flush();
        System.out.println(data.toByteArray().length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, the result is surprising, it takes 81 bytes. If I serialize `String` "1", it only takes 8 bytes instead. I know java has optimization for String serialization, but why not do the same thing for Integer? I think it shouldn't be very difficult.

Or does anyone has some workaround? I need a method which can serialize everything include objects and basic types. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What happens if you call writeInt instead of writeObject?  This should avoid auto boxing the int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a balancing act, between making the serialization protocol more complicated by having *direct* support for lots of types, and between keeping it simple.

In my experience, `Integer` values are relatively rare compared with `int` values - and the latter *does* have built-in support, along with all the other primitive types. It's also worth noting that although serializing a *single* `Integer` object is expensive, the incremental cost is much smaller, because there's already a reference to the class in the stream. So after the first `Integer` has been written, a new `Integer` only takes 10 bytes - and a reference to an `Integer` which has already been written to the stream (common if you're boxing small values) is only 5 bytes.

Personally I would try to avoid native Java binary serialization anyway - it's platform specific and *very* brittle, as well as not being terribly compact. I like [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com) but there are lots of other alternatives available too.